# Can I 'alias' a Rails active model to another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First off I am sure I am not asking this question correctly as this is an advanced Rails topic over my head right now.  Here is what I have for routes:

```
concern :assetable do
  resources :assets, concerns: [:workable, :trackable, :flagged, :historical, :commentable, :uploadable], shallow: true do
    resources :assets, path: :components, as: :components, shallow: true#, only: [:index, :create, :new]
  end
end
```

and my asset model:

```
has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy
alias_attribute :components, :assets
```

My premise here is I have an `Asset` model that can polymorphicly belong to pretty much any other model in my Rails app - including another `Asset`.  My my case I am limiting this case to one level deep and calling these `Components`.  This is like having a car as an asset and it has an engine, transmission etc. as a component.  For my purposes it's simple enough to make a common set of attributes that are shared between both the assets and components,

Now I could just create an entire new model but the entire data structure, views controllers etc are for the most part the same so I figured that was just a waste of time and makes it a mess to keep this code in sync.

As I go along now I am having to add some logic to my views to ensure the headings i.e. "Assets" vs. "Components" and I have a simple instance variable in my controller `@asset_class` which returns 'asset' or 'component'.  The ugly part now is when I start working with routes.  All the awesome Rails url helpers etc. fail me here because if I call `url_for( )` on a component record I get `/assets/etc/etc` when I really want `/components/etc/etc/`.  I essentially want to Assets nested under Assets to be represented as Component class not Asset.

Can I do this?  I think this is easier way but I am open to other suggestions (and question edits) because I may be way off here on my logic and design.

** UPDATE **

Here is some more background from the first comment:

So in my `Asset` show controller I deliberately added an exception to illustrate this.  Here is my url:

> http://localhost:3000/components/5

and from my error console I have:

```
>> @asset
=> #<Asset id: 5, assetable_id: 1, assetable_type: "Asset", name: "...>
>> url_for(@asset)
=> "http://localhost:3000/assets/5"
>> component_path(@asset)
=> "/components/5"
>> asset_path(@asset)
=> "/assets/5"
```

I know that I could use `component_path(@asset)` but `url_for` is much cleaner if I can let Rails do all the work vs constantly having to add some conditional logic every time I want to add a `link_to` etc.  I also see that I need to add some conditionals to my routes based on `assessable_type` as `Assets` should not show up in `Components` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating a Component class that inherits from Asset so that you can store all those in the assets table but treat them differently. This is generally called single table inheritance.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: That was awesome. I have some small logic to still sort out. Just a few points: you need to create a Components controller and inherit it from the Assets (unless you want your own). Same goes for Pundit policies but in my case I had to create a separate scope anyway. The controller logic is easy - you can call controller_name and set the Asset class for each type.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your *components* routes like so:

```
resources :components, controller: 'assets', path: :components, as: :components, shallow: true#, only: [:index, :create, :new], defaults: { components: true }
```

This uses the technique described in [Specifying a Controller to Use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) section of the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  It also uses the `defaults` option from the [Defining Defaults](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#defining-defaults) section of the same guide to inform the controller that it's using a *components* route and not an *assets* route.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I tried that but it does not solve my issue.  I have added some more details because as I mentioned I perhaps am not explaining the problem clearly.  The issue is not using named routes it's rails creation of the named routes based on the class of the active record result.